# Add class to parent div for each instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a wrapper div called container and inside that container div I have multiple instances of a div called mix. Inside each `mix` there is a class called `changeclass` with a text value. I need to add the text value of each `changeclass` div to its parent mix div as a class.

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active2</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active3</p>

  </div>
</div>
  <div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active4</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far in my research, I have been able to add the class the parent div of one but not each individual instance of this.

I've been using this

```
var str = $( ".classchange" ).text();
$( ".classchange" ).parent().addClass( str );
```

But I'm not sure how to add .each function to it to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `.each` of the `.mix`es, selecting the text in each one's `classchange` and calling `addClass` on the `.mix` with that text:

```js
$('.mix').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass(
    $(this).find('p').text()
  );
});

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active2</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active3</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active4</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since all your `classchange` are inside `mix`, u could `document.querySelectorAll(path)` which will return u a `NodeList`.

Then, u could convert it to an array data structure and apply `map` or `forEach` operations on them, where u could work with each `classChange` node and it's parent/s.

This is what I would do in ES6, not sure about JQuery but I'll let this here in case it helps at all.

Answer (score -1):

So, you want to add the new class to each `.mix` element right?

If so, then we could iterate on each `.classchange` element and add the new class from there. Like so:

```
$('.classchange').each(function() {
  $(this).parent('.mix').addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To better control the behavior of each matching element use the [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to loop over the target elements and control the DOM manipulation of each parent `.mix` individually:

```js
// Loop through all .classchange div
$('.classchange').each(function() {
  // Select closest .mix div add add new class based on current target text
  $(this).closest('.mix').addClass($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}

.active2 {
  color: hotpink;
}

.active3 {
  color: purple;
}

.active4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active2</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active3</p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="mix">
  <div class="classchange">
    <p>active4</p>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code was basically adding all 4 active classes to all `.mix` divs.